# Find unique portfolio combinations in R

Tags: r

Given a vector of stock ticker symbols:

```
 sp500 <- c("ABT", "ANF", "ADBE", "AMD", "AES", "AET" .. )
```

How do I find all unique combinations of these for a portfolio of N assets? So for example if N=3 I'd like to return a table/matrix:

```
  A1   |    A2    |    A3
--------------------------
"ABT"      "ANF"     "ABDE"
"ABT"      "AMD"     "ABDE"
"ABT"      "AMD"     "AES"
  .          .          .
  .          .          .
"YHOO"    "YUM"      "ZMH"
```

The order does not matter, so it's a "combination" rather than a "permutation", I believe.. 
I'm attempting to use R for this.

Advice on which function/method I might use for this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`help.search("combination")` would have given you the answer:

```
combn(sp500,3)
```